# Can I monkey patch the phantomjs browser api with execute_script?

Tags: poltergeist

Im trying to test an application with some native JavaScript features disabled e.g. querySelector ...

So I thought this might work before the call to visit:

```
page.execute_script("document.querySelector = null")
```

but it doesn't work, any thoughts on how I could achieve this?

Cheers
John

Comment: I'm afraid the last line is hard to parse: "Before the visit call, but it doesn't any thoughts on how I could achieve this?" Can you try to elaborate?

Comment: Hopefully a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`:extensions` option](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#customization). This allows you to define a JS file which gets preloaded into the browser.